# if/then formula with 3 conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

seeking help with a formula for If/and-then... that has 3 conditions

- If B2=yes and B4=0, "200"
- If B2=yes and B4=1, "100"
- otherwise, "0"

I've tried a few alterations but keep getting the "too many arguments" error. Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work? Please and thank you!

Comment: Could you list the alterations you have tried? Use the EDIT button to add them to the original question. This will help prevent us from duplicating work you've already done, and may help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: Try to use **IFS** function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
=IF(B2="yes",IF(B4=0,200,IF(B4=1,100,0)),0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It sure does work :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using IF/AND.  @cybernetic.nomad's answer achieves the same result using nested IF statements and less code.

`=IF(AND(B2="yes",B4=0),200,IF(AND(B2="yes",B4=1),100,0))`